# Invoking API calls with parameters specified using JSON

Tags: java, json, reflection

I have an instance of a Java class that I need to call some functions on, using the API exposed by another party. For each call, I need to both check for thrown exceptions, and check the value of the returned boolean. If the boolean is false, I need to read the errorMsg object to see what went wrong. In either error case, I need to throw an exception with a relevant method. Each method takes a different number of String arguments

I think there's a cleaner way to do this using reflection, but I can't figure out how to handle the different numbers of arguments. And there may be a totally different solution I've overlooked. Open to all suggestions. Any thoughts?

Here are two examples so you can see what I'm dealing with:

```
ClassProvidedWithExposedAPI s;

private void setHttp(JsonObject jo) throws Exception {
    boolean success = true;
    String errorString = null;
    ArrayList<Message> errorMsg = new ArrayList<Message>();
    try {
        JsonObject http = jo.getAsJsonObject("http");
        if (http != null && !http.isJsonNull()) {
            success = s.setHttp(getJsonElementAsString(http, Http.ENABLED_ELEMENT),
                    getJsonElementAsString(http, Http.HTTP_PORT_ELEMENT),
                    getJsonElementAsString(http, Http.HTTPS_PORT_ELEMENT),
                    getJsonElementAsString(http, Http.TIMEOUT_ELEMENT),
                    getJsonElementAsString(http, Http.HTTP_REDIRECT_ELEMENT), errorMsg);
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        errorString = e.toString();
    } finally {
        if (!success) {
            if (errorString == null) {
                errorString = errorMsg.toString();
            }
            throw new Exception("Exception in setHttp: " + errorString);
        }
    }
}

private void setSsh(JsonObject jo) throws Exception {
    boolean success = true;
    String errorString = null;
    ArrayList<Message> errorMsg = new ArrayList<Message>();
    try {
        JsonObject ssh = jo.getAsJsonObject("ssh");
        if (ssh != null && !ssh.isJsonNull()) {
            success = s.setSsh(getJsonElementAsString(ssh, Ssh.ENABLED_ELEMENT),
                    getJsonElementAsString(ssh, Ssh.SSH_PORT_ELEMENT),
                    getJsonElementAsString(ssh, Ssh.TIMEOUT_ELEMENT), errorMsg);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        errorString = e.toString();
    } finally {
        if (!success) {
            if (errorString == null) {
                errorString = errorMsg.toString();
            }
            throw new Exception("Exception in setSsh: " + errorString);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! I hope you get some good answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like a simple use case for polymorphism:

```
interface JsonOperation {
    void run();
}

private void setHttp(JsonObject jo) {
    runAndHandleErrors(() -> {
        // ...
    });
}

private void setSsl(JsonObject jo) {
    runAndHandleErrors(() -> {
        // ...
    });
}

private void runAndHandleErrors(JsonOperation op) {
    try {
        op.run();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // ...
    } finally {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Explanation: `JsonOperation` is an interface with one method so it is considered a *functional interface*, meaning a lambda can be considered an implementation of it. `runAndHandleErrors` takes a `JsonOperation` so whenever we call `runAndHandleErrors` with a lambda, the compiler infers the lambda to implement `JsonOperation`.

A lambda, like an anonymous inner class, captures final variables in enclosing blocks. That means that a lambda, like an anonymous inner class, can use these variables and sees the values of the variables that were assigned when the lambda / anonymous inner class was created. A lambda also captures variables that are *effectively final*, meaning their values are never changed whether or not they are declared as final.

When `setHttp(x)` is called, the following happens:

1. `x` is assigned to `jo`
2. an implementation of `JsonOperation` capturing `jo` is created (but not run)
3. `runAndHandleErrors` is called and the `JsonOperation` from step 2 is assigned to `op`
4. `runAndHandleErrors` calls `op.run()`, causing the `JsonOperation` to run
5. the `JsonOperation` runs, doing whatever it wants with `jo` - it sees the same value of `jo` as was assigned in step 2

---

However, since you posted to the Code Review Stack Exchange and not Programmers Stack Exchange, I'll critique your code:

- `catch Exception` and `throws Exception` are code smells - to the greatest degree possible, catch and declare specific Exception types.
- The logic regarding `success` and `errorString` is convoluted. You could instead separately throw an appropriate subclass of `Exception` in the `try` and `catch` blocks and get rid of the `success` and `errorString` variables. Your code reuse isn't actually helping because you need conditional logic in the `finally` block to account for both cases. Also, the thrown exception in the `catch` block should properly *wrap* the original exception by passing the latter directly into the former's constructor.
- Make a helper method for getJsonElementAsString that takes a varargs array of attribute keys and returns a list of attributes. This method would make your code much terser.

Comment: I like where this is going, but I'm not too familiar with the use of lambdas. Can you explain to me how this all hangs together? How do I get the JsonOperations inside of runAndHandleErrors()? Do the I write the s.setHttp(...) call in a Class that implements JsonOperation?

Thanks for the critique, and my bad if I posted this in not-quite-the-correct-stack-exchange.

Comment: I will explain the lambdas in my post as it provides a better environment for extended description than the comments and it is permanent, unlike comments.

Comment: If I apply these changes (or any others) am I supposed to post the updated code?

Comment: @PunDefeated Only if you seek additional feedback, in which case I suggest you post another question.